# forwarded value different between python and DJL

Tags: java, kotlin, pytorch, torchscript, djl

I see example https://docs.djl.ai/jupyter/load_pytorch_model.html
I made my own `torchscript` witch named `qooModel.pt` file and `synset.txt`

I tried to imitate the example. Here is my code.

```kotlin
val translator = ImageClassificationTranslator.builder()
    .setPipeline(Pipeline().apply {
        add(Resize(128))
        add(ToTensor())
    })
    .optSynsetArtifactName("synset.txt")
    .build()


val criteria = Criteria.builder()
    .setTypes(Image::class.java, Classifications::class.java)
    .optApplication(Application.CV.IMAGE_CLASSIFICATION)
    .optModelPath(Paths.get("models/qooModel.pt"))
    .optTranslator(translator)
    .build()

val imgFactory = ImageFactory.getInstance()
val imgPath    = Paths.get(args.getOrElse(0){"./images/qoo_learning.png"})
val image      = imgFactory.fromFile(imgPath)

val model = ModelZoo.loadModel(criteria)


val predict = model.newPredictor()

val result = predict.predict(image)
print(result)

model.close()
```

My code does not makes error, but forwarded value in `result` looks strange.
I expect

```json
[
    {"class": "qoo", "probability": 0.9597}
]
```

but

```json
[
    {"class": "qoo", "probability": 0.00463}
]
```

printed.

I exepect `0.9597` because when I running under Python code in Google Colab

```py
import torch
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as T

tensor_transform = T.Compose([T.PILToTensor()])

image = Image.open("qoo_learning.png").convert("RGB").resize((128, 128))
img_tensor = tensor_transform(image).type(torch.FloatTensor)
img_tensor = torch.unsqueeze(img_tensor, 0)
model(img_tensor)
```

the result of code show me `tensor([[0.9597]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)`

**Questions.**

Q1. Why I cannot get correct result (likes 0.9597) in my Kotlin code?

Q2. What should I do for get correct result?

**My guess**

G1. there some issue between pytorch version between 2.0.1(I write torchscript) and 1.13.1(Kotlin use)

G2. I should use pytorch 2.0.1 in my kotlin code
....unfortunately I tried to use torch 2.0.1 but I couldn't understand document

```
Explicitly specify pytorch-native-xxx package version to override the version in the BOM.
```

and I could not find example about that

or

G1. My code wrong. It load model but it does not load pre-trained weights.

G2. I should fix my code

....example https://docs.djl.ai/jupyter/load_pytorch_model.html looks like using pre-trained model

but I think my code is almost same.

**My Develop Environment.**

I make my torchscript file(`qooModel.pt`) in Window 11, pytorch 2.0.1

I run my Kotlin code in macOS, I did not install torch by pip

... and it looks like running pytorch 1.13.1, look under debug log

```
[main] DEBUG ai.djl.pytorch.jni.LibUtils - Using cache dir: /Users/romeo/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.13.1-cpu-osx-aarch64
[main] DEBUG ai.djl.pytorch.jni.LibUtils - Loading native library: /Users/romeo/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.13.1-cpu-osx-aarch64/libc10.dylib
[main] DEBUG ai.djl.pytorch.jni.LibUtils - Loading native library: /Users/romeo/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.13.1-cpu-osx-aarch64/libtorch_cpu.dylib
[main] DEBUG ai.djl.pytorch.jni.LibUtils - Loading native library: /Users/romeo/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.13.1-cpu-osx-aarch64/libtorch.dylib
[main] DEBUG ai.djl.pytorch.jni.LibUtils - Loading native library: /Users/romeo/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.13.1-cpu-osx-aarch64/0.23.0-libdjl_torch.dylib
```

sorry about my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary** 
Image preprocessing incorrect

---

look at this kotlin code, it is part of code from question

```
val translator = ImageClassificationTranslator.builder()
.setPipeline(Pipeline().apply {
    add(Resize(128))
    add(ToTensor())
})
.optSynsetArtifactName("synset.txt")
.build()
```

and python code from question

```
tensor_transform = T.Compose([T.PILToTensor()])
```

Unfortunately, that are does not same. Python code wich do preprocessing should be

```
preprocess = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(128), transforms.ToTensor()])
```

I fix this problem...

1. fix my python code, about image preprocessing part
2. train my model again
3. export to torchscript
4. load torchscript model by kotlin code
5. It works well :)